# on bootstrap table column expand strangely

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a table and ,in the note column , i should add long note that area. When i add very long note, the line  expand but i just want to note settle new lines.
Example :
asyufgasdfhjdasfghfghasfhaahjfsghjahfjqjwjefqfeqwhkfwq

I want this :  
jdsaaafjasasjs   
ywewyuwqfyuyew   
quyduquyqewfyy

And my table's code : (I want to fix td with 'thisone' id)

```html
<div class="col-md-6">
<div class="content-box-large">
<div class="panel-heading">
<div class="panel-title">Notlar</div> 
<div class="panel-options">
<a href="#" data-rel="collapse"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></i></a>
<a href="#" data-rel="reload"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></i></a>
</div>
</div>   
<div class="panel-body">
<table class="table table-striped">
<?php if(mysqli_num_rows($listele)>0)
{ ?>
<thead>
   <tr>
    <th>Tarih</th>
    <th>Saat</th>
    <th>Dosya Notu</th>
    <th>Notu Kaydeden Kişi</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <?php
$i=1;

while($not=mysqli_fetch_array($listele)) 
{
$tarih=$not["tarih"];

?>
      <tr>
        <td><?php echo date("d/m/Y",strtotime($tarih)); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo date("H:i",strtotime($tarih)); ?></td>
        <td id="thisone"><?php echo $not["dosya_not"]; ?></td>
        <td><?php  echo $not["calisan_adi"]; ?></td>
      </tr>
      <?php
    $i++;
        }
    }?> 
  </tbody>
  </table>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    <table class="table table-striped">
      <tr>
        <td><input type="hidden" id="musteri_id" value="<?php echo $musteri_id; ?>"></td>
        <td id="not"><textarea class="form-control" id="not_degeri" placeholder="Notu Giriniz" rows="3"></textarea></td>
        <td id="buton"><button class="btn btn-primary" id="ekle">Yeni Not Ekle</button></td>
      </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
</di

v>
```

Comment: have you try "_word-wrap: break-word;_" to your **td**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use word breaking option in CSS

```
  td {
     word-break: break-all;
  }
```

```html
  
<style>
td { word-break: break-all; }
</style>

<div class="col-md-6">
<div class="content-box-large">
<div class="panel-heading">
<div class="panel-title">Notlar</div> 
<div class="panel-options">
<a href="#" data-rel="collapse"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></i></a>
<a href="#" data-rel="reload"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></i></a>
</div>
</div>   
<div class="panel-body">
<table class="table table-striped">
<thead>
   <tr>
    <th>Tarih</th>
    <th>Saat</th>
    <th>Dosya Notu</th>
    <th>Notu Kaydeden Kişi</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>sometext</td>
        <td>some text</td>
        <td id="thisone">lsdfjasdklfjasldajklsdfjkldfjklafsjklasdfjlkasdfjklafjklasdfjhklasdfjhklasdfjhklasdfajklasdfjklasdfjkl</td>
        <td>some text</td>
      </tr>
  </tbody>
  </table>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    <table class="table table-striped">
      <tr>
        <td><input type="hidden" id="musteri_id" value=""></td>
        <td id="not"><textarea class="form-control" id="not_degeri" placeholder="Notu Giriniz" rows="3"></textarea></td>
        <td id="buton"><button class="btn btn-primary" id="ekle">Yeni Not Ekle</button></td>
      </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```